# Asymmetric robust regression

Tags: regression, distributions, outliers, robust, symmetry

What are the methods for robust regression with asymmetric distribution of outliers?

I am specifically interested in equivalents of Huber and Tukey M-estimators. However, asymmetric heavy-tailed distributions could be useful as well.

Comment: Lots of papers [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=robust+regression+with+asymmetric+distributions&oq=robust+regression+with+asymmetric+distributions&aqs=chrome..69i57.15737j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)